# How to avoid the Hotspot getting disabled during an incoming/outgoing call?

Tags: calls, wifi-hotspot, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

I have turned on Hotspot and the data is being used on other Android device but when there is an incoming call the Hotspot gets disabled automatically and gets enabled after the call ,During which I am unable to share the data.

Why is this happening and how to avoid the Hotspot getting disabled automatically on an incoming/outgoing call.

Comment: My Samsung Galaxy S3 was able to do hotspot and voice call at the same time. Upgraded to an S6 and now I have to choose one or the other. So I am not so sure this is a hard limitation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately a limitation in 3g is that data cannot be used whilst a voice call is happening. Android turns off the hotspot because data isn't available during the call, so unfortunately there is no fix available until networks start to implement voice over LTE.

Comment: It's not 3G it's 2G

Comment: Same limitation unfortunately

Comment: What does it mean and how can I check whether any other service provider supports this or an advanced version of this,

Comment: You cant do it anywhere. Basically your phone has a radio in that is used to communicate with the network. That radio can only be used for voice calls OR data. Not  both. Your phone will switch between the two uses depending on what you're doing, but when you're on a call the phone can't use mobile data. It's not a provider limitation, its just how phones are. There is a new technology coming in that does support this, but its in very early stages of deployment and you won't find anywhere offering it. It's called Voice over LTE, using the 4G network for voice rather than the old 3G network.

Comment: So if I have 3G device does it mean that the Calls , mobile data by default are made using this 3G where I have option for data to choose either 2G or 3G

Comment: Both 2G and 3G use the same radio so you can still only use either data or voice call at once.

Comment: For readers: I want to mention that in stock Android Marshmallow, hotspot is not turned off when a call is in place, be it incoming or outgoing.

Comment: That answer is not accurate. I was able to make a phone call and stay on the hotspot with an iphone on AT&T's network. Same carrier, but it doesn't work with Android. You can't blame that entirely on the network.

Comment: I think AT&T are now using VoLTE, which would allow this in certain places with certain handsets. Looks like they are marketing it as [HD Voice](https://www.att.com/shop/wireless/features/hd-voice.html) and only allow it to work on iPhones. Android has VoLTE support but it's up to handset manufacturers to make it work, not Android.

Comment: The solution described at https://qr.ae/pNBW4z works.

Answer (score -1):

You can use whats'up or some  voip application like skype or   CS-IP  app with voip provider credential. In the last case You can have a fixed phone number, , Just ask people to call You ate the virtual number.

Comment: >"Just ask people to call You ate the virtual number". Can you explain what you meant?