# How can I prevent wireless tethering from being disabled when I receive a call?

Tags: calls, wifi-tethering, 7.1-nougat, oneplus-3

I use my phone (a OnePlus 3 running the stock ROM and Android 7.1.1) as my primary internet connection. This means that I make heavy use of wireless tethering, especially for work. The trouble is, whenever my phone rings, regardless of whether I answer it, wireless tethering gets disabled. If I use USB tethering, I have no such problem, but wireless is much more convenient.

I previously came across [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/112419/14562), but it doesn't apply to me. I've never had a phone which was unable to simultaneously use phone and data. When I'm on a call, I can enable wireless tethering with no problem. It just gets disabled for no good reason whenever I receive a call.

Note that that the issue is *not* the connection technology (WCDMA, VoLTE, carrier support, etc.) This is absolutely impossible, since the fact mentioned above that I can manually re-enable tethering while on a call, coupled with the fact that I have full access to data while on a call, disproves any such theories. This is why I started a new thread instead of using the old one I linked to above.

**Is there any way to prevent wireless from being disabled?** Failing my first question, **I would also accept a method to make my phone completely ignore incoming calls during specified times so that they couldn't disable tethering, so long as I kept internet access and text messaging.**

Comment: It has two SIM slots, but I only have a single SIM for it. I see no reason to pay for two phone subscriptions.

Comment: For second part  (ignoring calls ) you could try [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid). Trigger: call incoming> any number; Action;: call reject:; constraints: WiFi hotspot State > WiFi hotspot on. If this solved your problem and you want me to post this as an answer, please tag me to post as I would be logged out

Answer (score 0):

On my LG K20 running 7.0 I have “Do Not Disturb” under” Settings > Sound & Notification”. With that turned on, incoming calls do not turn the WiFi hotspot off. I just now tested it to make sure. I can leave it on until I switch it back off again myself or I can set a timer that will turn “Do Not Disturb” off after a specified length of time.